# Is it necessary to implement both LoaderCallbacks and OnLoadCompleteListener to get notifications of changes in a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I have an application which is using `Loader`s to get at a database which is also being edited by an `IntentService`.  I receive data from the `Loader` through a `LoaderCallbacks` implementation, which is working fine.

I am also using `ContentResolver#notifyChange(Uri, ContentObserver)` to trigger reload.  However, this only works when I call `Cursor#setNotificationUri(Uri)` beforehand.

I can find no reference to the latter method in any documentation and it seems in fact this may be causing crashes: see also

[IllegalStateException "attempt to re-open an already-closed object" in SimpleCursorAdapter from ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956608/illegalstateexception-attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-in-simplecur)

However, without this call on the `Cursor` the `LoaderCallbacks#onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor>, Cursor)` is only hit after the initial load, and not after the notification.  Do I *also* need to implement an `OnLoadCompleteListener` to do, well, exactly the same thing?

`ContentProvider` query method:

```
class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {
//...

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor query = db.query(getTableName(uri), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        query.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return query;
    }

//...
}
```

Typical `LoaderCallbacks`:

```
LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mArticleAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor.isClosed()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CURSOR RETURNED CLOSED");
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if(activity!=null) {
                activity.getLoaderManager().restartLoader(mFragmentId, null, mCallbacks);
            }
            return;
        }
        mArticleAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        triggerArticleFeed();
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;

        if(id == mFragmentId) {
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                                            MyContentProvider.ARTICLES_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ArticlesContentHelper.ARTICLES_WHERE,
                                            ArticlesContentHelper.ARTICLES_WHEREARGS,
                                            null);
        }
        return(cursorLoader);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you post onLoadFinished method ?

Comment: Is it your own content provider or some other content provider?

Comment: @Saksak I've put those in.

Comment: @ebarrenchea it's our `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Do you know if it's necessary to implement both callbacks?

Comment: It's not. calling setNotificationUri along with the normal Loader callbacks is enough.

Comment: this exception occur when you explicitly close the cursor , can you post your Adapter check if you are doing anything to the cursor in it ?

Comment: @dymmeh OK ... in that case have you any idea what's causing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956608/illegalstateexception-attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-in-simplecur

Comment: @Saksak I don't close the cursor *anywhere*.  It's the first thing I checked.

Comment: @AndrewWyld - you are destroying the loader manually.. why? This is pointless since it's automatically managed.

Comment: @dymmeh that was something I tried in order to fix the crash; this app is single-orientation only except in one `Activity` and we're implementing `onConfigurationChanged` in that.  I'll get rid of that though and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @AndrewWyld - what does triggerArticleFeed(); do?

Comment: @AndrewWyld can you try and remove the check cursor.isClosed() ? comment it and just call the swap

Comment: @Saksak again, this is something I added to try and fix the problem based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999098/illegalstateexception-support-loadermanager-with-autocompletetextview the bug was present before.

Comment: @dymmeh it calls the `IntentService` that repopulates the database.     `private void triggerArticleFeed() {
     Context context = getActivity();
     if(context == null) return;
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, FeedIntentService.class);
     intent.setAction(MyContentProvider.ARTICLES_URI.toString());
     context.startService(intent);
    }`

Comment: I just noticed you are passing `null` for your projection when you create your cursor loader. I'm not sure what would happen in that case, but maybe that is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @ebarrenchea the google example is done with a null `Bundle`: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html so I doubt it's the problem.

Comment: @ebarrenchea - null projection just means you return all columns available. Not efficient but won't cause any crashes.

Comment: @AndrewWyld - Can you show your adapter creation? If you are using the deprecated SimpleCursoradapter constructor you will run into this problem.

Comment: @dymmeh sure, but shall I do it on the other question?

Comment: @AndrewWyld - sure. that will be better. I'll monitor that one

Comment: @dymmeh done.  It's the bottom code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing both listeners is a very bad idea:

```
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886): java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is already a listener registered
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886):    at android.content.Loader.registerListener(Loader.java:152)
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.start(LoaderManager.java:273)
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.installLoader(LoaderManager.java:523)
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:510)
02-19 17:46:25.139: E/AndroidRuntime(24886):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:563)
```

So in fact the answer to this question is:

It is necessary **NOT** to implement both listeners.